# What's the best way to level transport helicopters as a pilot?

Tags: battlefield-3

I want to level transport helicopters in Battlefield 3.  What's the best way to earn points?  Do I only get points for kills from my passengers or is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a pilot in a transport helicopter, the best way to get points is to cap flags.  I would guess you could also use the helicopter to run over infantry (untested, but seems likely).  Spotting targets will also get you some points and make your teammates happy.

There are no unlocks for the transport helicopters though, so you won't get much (if anything) for your efforts.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there were no upgrades. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, It would be cool if there were some upgrades, at least for the passenger seats.  Like IRNV on the guns or something.  IDK, maybe it would make it overpowered.  And the pilot should get extra points for taking teammates to the flag.  I feel like that would persuade more people to use this vehicle.

Comment: There are IR flare upgrades for the transport helipcopters

Answer (score 2):

You can hover around or land next to a flag to cap it for points.

The scout helicopters are the AH-6J LITTLE BIRD and Z-11W.  Which have pretty awesome infantry killing mini guns.  Which should give you points to level up.  Once you get the heat seekers you are a killing machine.

Comment: Yah, but as a pilot, I mean. I shoulda said that in my question.

Comment: @Yatrix the pilot can operate the forward facing miniguns on the scout helicopter (and eventually the missiles).  Are you talking the the transport choppers, where there are guns on the sides?  The transport helicopters don't have any upgrades.

Comment: I think he might be talking about the transport choppers (UH-1Y Vemon & KA-60 Kasakta). The transport choppers have no weapons operable by the pilot. @Yatrix Are you?

Comment: Yes. I'll change my question. I thought those were scout helis.

Comment: Gave you an upvote since I asked the wrong question. =)